# Extract C++ template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, rtti

Although I'm doubtful, I'm curious as to whether it's possible to extract primitive-type template parameters from an existing type, perhaps using RTTI.

For example:

```
typedef std::bitset<16> WordSet;
```

Would it be possible to extract the number 16 in the above code without hard-coding it elsewhere? Compiler specific implementations are welcome, though I'm particularly interested in `g++`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It's not possible in general to pick arbitrary template parameters.

However, the usual way you do it is this:

```
template<int N>
struct foo {
    static const int value = N;
};
```

and for types

```
template<typename T>
struct foo {
    typedef T type;
};
```

You can access it then as `foo<39>::value` or `foo<int>::type`.

If you have a particular type, you can use partial template specialization:

```
template<typename>
struct steal_it;

template<std::size_t N>
struct steal_it< std::bitset<N> > {
    static const std::size_t value = N;
};
```

The same principle is possible for type parameters too, indeed. Now you can pass any bitset to it, like `steal_it< std::bitset<16> >::value` (note to use size_t, not int!). Because we have no variadic many template paramters yet, we have to limit ourself to a particular parameter count, and repeat the steal_it template specializations for count from 1 up to N. Another difficulty is to scan types that have mixed parameters (types and non-types parameters). This is probably nontrivial to solve.

If you have not the type, but only an object of it, you can use a trick, to still get a value at compile time:

```
template<typename T>
char (& getN(T const &) )[steal_it<T>::value];  

int main() {
    std::bitset<16> b;
    sizeof getN(b); // assuming you don't know the type, you can use the object
}
```

The trick is to make the function template auto-deduce the type, and then return a reference to a character array. The function doesn't need to be defined, the only thing needed is its type.

Comment: Nice trick.  One thing though, you start by saying how it's not possible, but then proceed to show that it is! :)

Comment: @Richard Corden: I think he was saying it's not possible to do using RTTI

Comment: Richart Corden. I meant it's generally not possible to pick arbitrary template parameters. consider this:   template<template<class, int> class, class, size_t> class foo; that trick won't get their types :)

Answer (score 13):

You can easily do this in C++11 using argument deduction and unevaluated contexts (note that demo uses C++14's variable template feature for convenience).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<int>
struct foo {};

template<int arg_N>
struct val {
    static constexpr auto N = arg_N;
};

template<template <int> typename T, int N>
constexpr auto extract(const T<N>&) -> val<N>;

template<typename T>
constexpr auto extract_N = decltype(extract(std::declval<T>()))::N;


int main() {
    std::cout << extract_N<foo<5>>;
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/498365c253663e80)

Answer (score 8):

I like Marc Garcia's answer because it shows how to extract the template parameter in a generic way, but I believe his example can be simpler:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<int>
struct MyType {};

template<template <int> typename T, int N>
constexpr int extract(const T<N>&) { return N; }

int main() {
    constexpr MyType<5> myObj;
    std::cout << extract(myObj);
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/edd4525fb4eb74a5)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `std::bitset`, you can just use the `size()` member function:

```
size_t sz = oh_my_word.size();  // sz is now 16
```

In the general case, you can define a member function which returns the size in a similar manner:

```
template <int N>
class Foo
{
public:
  int size() const { return N; }
};
```

Comment: I'm talking about extracting it from third-party classes with no `size()` method or anything similar -- extracting it just knowing the type itself. The reason being that I don't want to have to make a dummy instance just to get the size of the typedef'd bitset.

Comment: It's not a particularly bad penalty for bitset, but there could be other types where instantiating a dummy type is undesirable or impractical.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by other answers, for `std::bitset` you can get the size by using the `size()` member function, which should be the right choice, better than any other trick.

There were several proposals for the generic case, almost similar to the one I suggest below, but still I think this one is simpler:

```
template <template<std::size_t> typename T, std::size_t K>
auto extractSize(const T<K>&) {
    return K;
}

int main() {
    std::bitset<6> f1;
    std::bitset<13> f2;
    std::cout << extractSize(f1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << extractSize(f2) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For very old C++ and integer types, a class enum replaces the non-working **static const** declaration.

```
template<int N> struct foo {
  enum{value=N};
};
```