# Taking type of a template class

Tags: c++, class, function, templates

Is there a way for taking type of a template class, for example

```
//i have template function
template<typename T>
IData* createData();

//a template class instance
std::vector<int> a;

//using type of this instance in another template
//part in quotation mark is imaginary of course :D
IData* newData = createData<"typeOf(a)">();
```

is it possible in c++? or is there an shortcut alternative

Comment: Not quite sure what you want. Are you trying to 'extract' the int type from std::vector<int> so that the type you're specifying for CreateData function is int instead of std::vector<int>?

Comment: If you mean what @Kei is suspecting, then here is a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301203/extract-c-template-parameters :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - Use [boost::typeof](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/typeof.html)

```
IData* newData = createData<typeof(a)>();
```

The new standard (`C++0x`) will provide a builtin way for this.

Note that you could give `createData` a dummy-argument which the compiler could use to infer the type.

```
template<typename T>
IData* createData(const T& dummy);

IData* newData = createData(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not clear what you are asking about. The templates parameter is its type, for example:

```
template<typename T> IData* createData() {
   return new T();
}
```

Now we can say:

```
IData * id = createData <Foo>();
```

which will create a new Foo instance, which had better be derived from Idata.