# Carrying type information in class template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I need to access type information from a class I used to instantiate another class.

Specifically `void Beta<T>::do_something()` needs to accept parameters of type `W, S` that were used to instantiate class `Alpha<W, S>`.

```
template<typename W, S> 
class Alpha {
public:
  using carry_W = W;
  using carry_S = S;
};

template<typename T> 
class Beta {};
template<typename T>
void Beta<T>::do_something(typename T::carry_W p1, typename T::carry_S p2) {}

Beta<Alpha<int, double>> b;
```

The solution above works fine but is there any other way to do this without aliasing the  types as class members? Is there a more "C++" way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can one access the template parameter outside of a template without a typedef?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696286/can-one-access-the-template-parameter-outside-of-a-template-without-a-typedef)

Comment: Purely stylistic but I'd rather use something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2dbf6b21987a5a7b)

Comment: Why don't you just take all arguments with forwarding references and let validity inside `do_something` do the rest?

Comment: @Columbo not sure I get it, would it be possible to develop this more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class template that consists only of a forward declaration and a partial specialisation.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename W, typename S> 
class Alpha {
};

template<typename>
class Beta;

template<typename W, typename S, template<typename, typename> class T>
class Beta<T<W,S>> {
public:
  void do_something(W w, S s) {
      cout << w << ", " << s << '\n';
  }
};

int main() { 
    Beta<Alpha<int, double>> b;
    b.do_something(0, 0.0);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it would only match a specific template.

Comment: @FlorinGogianu Ah K, I though this was for some specific `Alpha`.

Comment: I guess this is the best we get. Thanks!

Comment: @FlorinGogianu, Is there any way I can expand on this for you? It seems to be a fairly exact match for your question.

Comment: I think I got it. Marked your take as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like the following (template 'pattern matching')?

```
template<typename T<W, S>>
void Beta<T>::do_something(W, S) {...}
```

While I think your question is totally legit, I fear that the current C++ does not allow this shortcut...

Comment: Yes, that would be something I guess. I was asking because the way I wrote it seems to me a bit of a hack and I was not sure if this is the accepted way of doing it.