# template template parameter of unknown type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

Trying to extract template parameter value in the following code:

```
template<std::size_t SIZE>
class Foo {};

template <template<std::size_t> class T, std::size_t K>
auto extractSize(const T<K>&) {
    return K;
}

int main() {
    Foo<6> f1;
    Foo<13> f2;
    std::cout << extractSize(f1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << extractSize(f2) << std::endl;
}
```

(As an answer for the question:
[Extract C++ template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301203/extract-c-template-parameters)).

However, is there a way to do it *without knowing the type of the template parameter*. Something like (code below doesn't compile...):

```
template <template<class SIZE_TYPE> class T, SIZE_TYPE K>
auto extractSize(const T<K>&) {
    return K;
}
```

The compilation error on the above, is:

```
error: unknown type name 'SIZE_TYPE'
template <template<class SIZE_TYPE> class T, SIZE_TYPE K>
                                             ^
```

Comment: Did you try to put '''typename SIZE_TYPE''' at the beggining of the list?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Adding typename SIZE_TYPE [fails with C++14](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cfb21497d98525b). It does work [with C++17](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/368d3668d140ea71) - but if we are in C++17, the solution with `auto` proposed by Rakete1111 would be simpler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`auto` to the rescue!

```
template <template<auto> class T, auto K>
auto extractSize(const T<K>&) {
    return K;
}
```

That way the type of the value you passed in as template parameter is automatically inferred.

Comment: Doesn't that depend on `Foo` accepting an `auto` non-type parameter, and not a `std::size_t`? I'm not clear on the deduction rules here

Comment: @StoryTeller Nope, it doesn't :)

Comment: Very nice indeed :)

Comment: This is neat, didn't even think this would be possible!

Comment: Cool. Works well [for C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026884/advantages-of-auto-in-template-parameters-in-c17), not for C++14.
Any suggestion for C++11/14?

Comment: @AmirKirsh `auto` template parameter is introduced in C++17, no such solution for C++14.

Comment: @AmirKirsh I can't find one. Maybe someone else can. I'll be still trying though.

Comment: There isn't a way in pre-C++17, assuming you are using a standard compliant compiler and not typing from memory (*smh*). My own attempt fails at https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp#deduct.type-5.3

Comment: @StoryTeller the compiler in one's head tends to be permissive :-) It seems that your answer closes it. Applause for C++17 auto template parameter!