# Template argument with default type and value

Tags: c++, templates, types, arguments, default

I would like to give a template argument a default type and value. The argument isn't really used, it's only relevant to distinguish class instances. I want to use the mechanic for to give classes a key.

I'm trying something like this but the compiler doesn't like it

```cpp
template<typename K = int>
template<typename T, K Key = K(0)>
class DataAction : public Action
{
    // ...
};
```

Type `T` hold data for me. Type `Key` is of some value to allow for easy use of `enum class` types and should default to `int 0` if not assigned.

The following would work.

```
template<typename T, typename K = int, K Key = K(0)>
class DataAction : public Action
```

But it requires me to first define the type and then the value, which is not nice.

```cpp
auto instance = DatatAction<int, SomeEnumType, SomeEnumType::SomeKey>();
```

The intention is that the user might want to use multiple class instances of DataAction with the same data type `T`. To be able to distinguish between them in a dynamic_cast, which is required anyway, an additional key type is used.

Comment: OK, seems to be a thing that C++17 solved but not C+11 which I'm stuck with.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608830/template-template-parameter-of-unknown-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++17 you can use an *auto* template parameter:

```
template <typename T, auto = 0>
class DataAction : public Action
{
}
```

Here 0 is an int, but you could assign (char)0 or other types too, if you really want to be confusing with different types of the same value.  :)

Personally I prefer a single type and no defaults for this kind of thing.  This avoids most accidental key reuse and confusion by onlookers.